# How to get unique cell id for Angular UI-Grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Is it possible to get unique cell ids in UI-Grid?

Every time i navigate in my application the gridData is initialized and col.uid changes.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need an unique id for every cell something like id="row-1-column-1" and so on.
This id will be used for ui integrity tests.